Efficiently decomposing `SQRT_ZZ` into dissipative gates
The following stim circuit is equivalent to SQRT_ZZ 0 1, up to pauli feedback, while using only gates from the set MX, MY, MZ, MXX, MYY, MZZ:
MZ 2
MYY 1 2  # this is effectively doing H 1
MX 2
MZZ 0 2  # this is effectively doing CX 0 1
MXX 1 2
MZ 2
MYY 1 2  # this is effectively doing H 1
MX 2
MZZ 1 2  # this is effectively doing S 1
MY 2
MZZ 0 2  # this is effectively doing S 0
MX 2

Let's arbitrarily say that single qubit dissipative gates are free. Then the cost of this circuit is six two-qubit dissipative gates.
Is it possible to decompose SQRT_ZZ into fewer than six two-qubit dissipative gates, in this gate set?

Here is a method you can use to verify that a circuit implements another, up to Pauli feedback:
import stim  # ~=1.14.dev

def implements_flows_up_to_pauli_feedback_of(implemented_circuit: stim.Circuit, target_circuit: stim.Circuit) -> bool:

    def flow_to_key_ignoring_pauli_feedback(flow: stim.Flow) -> tuple[str, str]:
        inp = flow.input_copy()
        out = flow.output_copy()
        while len(inp) > 0 and inp[-1] == 0:
            inp = inp[:-1]
        while len(out) > 0 and out[-1] == 0:
            out = out[:-1]
        inp.sign = +1
        out.sign = +1
        return str(inp), str(out)

    if implemented_circuit.num_qubits < target_circuit.num_qubits:
        # Expand the size of the circuit to get the relevant doing-nothing flows it implements.
        implemented_circuit = implemented_circuit + stim.Circuit(f"I {target_circuit.num_qubits - 1}")

    implemented_generators = implemented_circuit.flow_generators()
    target_generators = target_circuit.flow_generators()
    implemented_keys = {flow_to_key_ignoring_pauli_feedback(flow) for flow in implemented_generators}
    for flow in target_generators:
        if not flow_to_key_ignoring_pauli_feedback(flow) in implemented_keys:
            return False

    return True


It looks like this function returns false on the two inputs you provide?

@EvgeniyZh Whoops. I had copy-pasted by SQRT_XX implementation instead of SQRT_ZZ. Fixed now.

Here's a version with 3 (using two ancilla qubits instead of one, due to the Hadamard being on the ancilla):
MY 2
MZZ 1 2
MX 3
MYY 2 3
MZ 3
MZZ 0 2
MY 2

Based on this ZX graph:


Here's a version with 4:
MX 2
MYY 1 2
MZ 2
MY 2
MXX 1 2
MZZ 0 2
MY 2
MX 2
MYY 1 2
MZ 2

Bases on this ZX graph (the Hadamards are implemented using MYYs):

